# Stabilizer of the Galois group is open

Tags: general-topology, galois-theory

Let $k$ be a field and $\operatorname{Gal}(k)$ be its absolute Galois group. In the middle of the proof of theorem 1.5.2 in T. Szamuely's *Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups*, the author says that if $S$ is a finite set endowed with a continuous and transitive action of $\operatorname{Gal}(k)$ then the stabilizers of the points of $S$ are open in $\operatorname{Gal}(k)$.

I don't see why that is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is a group acting transitively and continuously on the finite set $S$ (with the discrete topology) and $P$ is the stabilizer of some point $s\in S$, then there is a homeomorphism
$$
h: G/P\to S, \ g\mapsto g\cdot s.
$$
In particular $P=h^{-1}(s)$ is open since $\{s\}$ is open in $S$.

[Perhaps more directly:  Continuity of the action $a: G\times S\to S$ implies that
$$
P\times\{s\}=a^{-1}(s)\cap G\times \{s\}
$$
is open.]

Comment: Could you explain a little more why this is a homeomorphism?